# is installing a module on a live site ill advised?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to install [Code Per Node](https://drupal.org/project/cpn) on my website.

All i have to do is ad content types that would accept HTML5 webgames.

There would be theming involved.

Is this a no go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully installed modules on sites with thousands hits a day. Maybe even an hour. And I must tell it's not wise, from the point of my experience. Sometimes you have no choice (installing captcha on the spam wave when client forbids technical break), but way to many things can go wrong. If your site has any significant number of visitors and you care about your reputation, either:

- Install module on a copy of your site
- Put your site in maintenance mode
- Add `.htaccess` "maintenance mode" screen
- Sync files
- Sync data

Or simplier, but with longer break:

- Put your site in maintenance mode
- Add `.htaccess` "maintenance mode" screen
- Install module

That way if your site dies, visitors will see nice static html screen saying "Sorry, technical break" and you will be able to revert from backups.

Comment: +1, but don't you think we could replace "technical break" with "maintenance mode" as that's the actual term Drupal uses? Saying technical break might be confusing.

Comment: @Letharion agreed and done. Why haven't you edited my post in the first place? I'm from non-english speaking country, I'm used to term translations sometimes. Especially when it's Marketing division who decides what clients will see on that screen in the first place ;)

Comment: Wasn't sure if you had a specific reason to use a different term, so didn't want to risk messing up your post. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule against installing a module on a live site. However, it is advised to test it out on a test server before deploying it to a live site.